# python webbrowser.open cannot open long url

Tags: python, url, long-integer

I tried to use webbrowser.open() function to open a long url in python, but it seems it cannot open a long url correctly. The string passed to this function is truncated to about 2083 bytes long and only the front part is opened. 
The code is sth like this

```
import webbrowser
url = 'www.google.com/parametersssssssssss....' #very very long
webrowser.open(url) #only front part is opened
```

No exception is tracked. Anyone has similar situation about it?

Comment: it is not a `webbrowser` limit, it is *real* browsers limit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Since `webbrowser` it is just iterface to allow displaying web-based documents it is not handling urls by himself.
There is just transferring of urls into installed browsers.

Good description of [`max length of URL in different browsers`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/3990145).